# Automatic publishing after some fixed intervals?

Tags: automation

Is it possible to publish "pending posts" automatically after some interval around the clock, using WP Cron or something else?

I receive over 2000 posts daily, submitted by visitors, and they all go to pending status. I cannot edit and schedule each post. Just looking for a way to auto-post the pending posts with some intervals. E.g. Publishing 20 posts after every 15 mins.

Comment: WP Corn.... MMMMmm tasty.

Comment: You might be able to use a solution similar to this: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104739/21376

Comment: What type of site is this (that receives 2000 submissions per day)? Link?

Comment: It is a photography site.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that there is information missing from this question but the obvious answer is to schedule your posts with the built in post publication scheduler.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but scheduling post will not work. Because I'm receiving 2000+ entries daily. I've found this php script. :) http://blog.jasonantman.com/2012/09/wordpress-automatically-publish-a-pending-post-each-weekday-morning-from-a-php-script/

Comment: I knew there was information missing! What do you mean by "receiving" entries? Edit that information into your question.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress supports scheduling posts to go live at some point in the future. WordPress.com goes into great detail explaining how to do this http://en.support.wordpress.com/posts/schedule-a-post/

WordPress' built-in cron might work for you just fine but it requires your site gets some amount of traffic for it to work properly. If you need cron to fire every hour on the hour then you can always disable WordPress' built-in cron and use a real cron job instead. See https://support.hostgator.com/articles/specialized-help/technical/wordpress/how-to-replace-wordpress-cron-with-a-real-cron-job